# tcpdf cyrillic letters displayed as question marks "?"

Tags: php, pdf, tcpdf, cyrillic

I had downloaded tcpdf and here you are - I have a problem.

simple html code

```
<p>Это тест</p>
```

works all right
[image]

```
$pdf = new TCPDF(PDF_PAGE_ORIENTATION, PDF_UNIT, PDF_PAGE_FORMAT, true, 'UTF-8', false);

$pdf->SetCreator(PDF_CREATOR);
$pdf->SetAuthor('Nicola Asuni');
$pdf->SetTitle('TCPDF Example 002');
$pdf->SetSubject('TCPDF Tutorial');
$pdf->SetKeywords('TCPDF, PDF, example, test, guide');

$pdf->setPrintHeader(false);
$pdf->setPrintFooter(false);

$pdf->SetDefaultMonospacedFont('freeserif');

$pdf->SetMargins(PDF_MARGIN_LEFT, PDF_MARGIN_TOP, PDF_MARGIN_RIGHT);

$pdf->SetAutoPageBreak(TRUE, PDF_MARGIN_BOTTOM);

$pdf->setImageScale(PDF_IMAGE_SCALE_RATIO);

$pdf->setFontSubsetting(true);

$pdf->SetFont('freeserif', '', 12, '', true);

$pdf->AddPage();

//simple html being shown ok
$pdf->writeHTML('<p>Это тест</p>');

$pdf->Output('example_002.pdf', 'D');
```

but when I try to convert my html page cyrillic symbols replaced by question marks "?"

```
$pdf->writeHTML($html);
```

[image]

Please help - I am googling for three days!

here is a link to my page so you can look at the source code
http://u1159833.cp.regruhosting.ru/co_constructor/page.php

Comment: Please update your question to provide the full html of the page you're converting.

Comment: What is PDF_FONT_NAME_MAIN value in tcpdf_config.php

Comment: Amir why are you asking about  PDF_FONT_NAME_MAIN

Comment: Does the font even contain the cyrillic glyphs?

Comment: as far as I know - it doesn't

Comment: The TCPDF version of the Arial font (Helvetica) that is included and loaded by default [(`PDF_FONT_NAME_MAIN`)](https://github.com/tecnickcom/TCPDF/blob/main/tcpdf.php#L1915), does not support Cyrillic. You would need to force the usage of a UTF-8 compatible font. I am not able to reproduce the issue by simply replacing your `$pdf->writeHTML('<p>Это тест</p>');` with `$pdf->writeHTML(file_get_contents('cyr.html'));`.   See [example image](https://i.imgur.com/nz8Rhsk.png), so are you doing something different, what version of PHP, TCPDF, are you running?

Comment: tcpdf version 6.4.4 php 7.3.33

Comment: Will B. please give me your code

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I need to have cyrillic symbols displayed instead of question marks

Comment: @Alex I used Save As `cyr.html` from your URL, copied your PHP snippet verbatim, added the inlcude for composer `autoloader.php` and replaced `$pdf->writeHTML('<p>Это тест</p>');` with `$pdf->writeHTML(file_get_contents('cyr.html'));` only. I've since deleted it. I tested using PHP 7.4.21 and TCPDF 6.4.2.